# Almacenar el valor de una celda on mouse over usando jQuery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

En una estructura de tablas bastante compleja necesito obtener el valor de una celda concreta al pasar el ratón por encima. La idea es que el valor se pueda almacenar de alguna manera global (por ejemplo como una variable de sesión) para luego poder ser utilizado en otras funciones.

Un extracto del HTML:

```html
<table id="invoicesList_list" onmousedown="genericMenu.show(event)" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <table width="730" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="table-row1" onmouseover="this.className='table-row-hover'" onmouseout="this.className='table-row1'" onmousedown="invoicesList.mouseSelect(event,0,'');"><td style="height:17px" valign="middle">
            <input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_rowSelect" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_rowId" value="658997773">
            <table class="txt-flat" id="invoicesList_rows_0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td title="" width="40" align="center">
                <a href="javascript:calculate()" class="txt-selectable-link"></a><input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_checked" value="0">
                </td>
                <td width="70" align="center">
                Prepay Technologies, SA<input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_operador" value="Operador s.a.">
                </td>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                253<input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_codi_operador" value="253">
                </td>
                <td width="60" align="center">
                50644<input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_machine" value="50644">
                </td>
                <td width="90" align="center">
                00000016<input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_simplified_invoice" value="00000016">
                </td>
                <td width="90" align="center">
                &nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_annuled_simplified_invoice" value="">
                </td>
                <td width="90" align="center">
                02/09/2019 23:00:31<input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_operationdate" value="02/09/2019 23:00:31">
                </td>
                <td width="70" align="center">
                871571076<input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_card" value="871571076">
                </td>
                <td width="90" align="center">
                780<input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_price" value="780">
                </td>
                <td width="70" align="center">
                <a href="javascript:generateReport('0')" class="txt-selectable-link">T-0001-2019</a>
                <input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_client_invoice" value="T-0001-2019">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Me interesa la última fila de la tabla interna, es decir:

```html
<td width="70" align="center">
    <a href="javascript:generateReport('0')" class="txt-selectable-link">T-0001-2019</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="invoicesList_client_invoice" value="T-0001-2019">
</td>
```

En concreto necesito almacenar `T-0001-2019`.

He intentado recuperar con jQuery utilizando la clase hover de la siguiente forma:

```
$('.txt-selectable-link').hover(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
        var invoiceCode = $(this).text();
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('invoiceCode',$(this).text());        
});
```

El alert funciona perfecto, mostrando el texto necesario. Sin embargo no consigo almacenarlo en variable global ni de sesión. También he intentado recuperar el valor al hacer hover sobre la tabla interna intentando capturar el campo hidden, pero imagino que algo he hecho mal (aunque he tenido que hacer muchas cosas en jQuery entenderlo es otro asunto):

```
$('.table-row-hover').hover(function(){
    var invoiceTable = $(this).find('table:first').parents('tr').find('#invoicesList_client_invoice input[type="hidden"]').val();
    alert(invoiceTable);
});
```

La dificultad añadida es que es código heredado que no puedo tocar porque la estructura mostrada se genera automáticamente para todas las listas de la aplicación desde Java, por lo que no tengo posibilidad de alterarla sin alterar al mismo tiempo todas las listas de la aplicación. Por eso necesito capturar la celda o el campo hidden en su defecto. ¿Alguna idea?. Gracias.

**EDIT**
He intentado utilizar `hover` y recoger el texto del link porque me parecía la opción más sencilla, pero si alguien sabe como coger el valor del campo `hidden` a través del `hover` me sería de mucha utilidad. Es decir, dada la estructura como saber qué campo oculto corresponde a la fila sobre la que se tiene el ratón.

Comment: Y te sale algún error en la consola?

Comment: Ningún error @BenderPaisa

Comment: y ya intentaste con localStorage?

Comment: Porque quieres almacenar-lo en sesión ?, cambias de página o similar ?
Es decir, en vez de realizar el proceso de asignar una sesión que irá reemplazando cada ms.; la session cuando el usuario desplace el mouse, prueba con un array, haciendo push y cúando quieras cambiar página o similar, crea la session con un JSON.stringify y la recuperas con JSON.parse como objeto de los datos que quieras

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño lo intento almacenar en sesión porque no me ha funcionado almacenarlo en una variable global. El valor se usa cuando el usuario invoca el menú contextual (modificado) y selecciona una opción (la de eliminar), momento en el cual se llama a otra función javascript que debe usar el valor almacenado.